# remove inner grid when placing frame around plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Please see this MWE:

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

There is one horizontal and one vertical line drawn that crosses zero - how do I remove these lines? I tried `GridLines->None`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever the rep-whore, here's my original comment made into an answer:

try adding `Axes->False` to the options in your Plot command.